# Google Line Chart with different Sample Interval

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm trying to draw multiple lines on a [line-chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart), but each line has a different data sampling interval - some every 4 hours, some every 8.

The data looks something like this if I merge the intervals together.

```
Interval, Avg-8h, Avg-4h
0       ,   0.45, 0.33
4       ,       , 0.21
8       ,   0.32, 0.55
12      ,       , 0.65
```

At the moment the best I can get is for the Avg-4h line to show up, but the Avg-8h line, because of the 'gaps', is just points.

A minimal example of this (apologies for the large swath of HTML):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     var data;
     var chart;
      google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = {
            "cols": [
                { "label": "Interval", "type": "number" },
                { "label": "Avg-8h", "type": "number" },
                { "label": "Avg-4h", "type": "number" }],
            "rows": [
                { "c": [{ "v": 24 }, { "v": 0.2275 }, { "v": 0.1527 }] },
                { "c": [{ "v": 20 }, { }, { "v": 0.0664 }] },
                { "c": [{ "v": 16 }, { "v": 0.0624 }, { "v": 0.0495 }] },
                { "c": [{ "v": 12 }, { }, { "v": 0.0555 }] },
                { "c": [{ "v": 8 }, { "v": 0.109 }, { "v": 0.1112 }] },
                { "c": [{ "v": 4 }, { }, { "v": 0.1403 }] },
                { "c": [{ "v": 0 }, { "v": 0.1403 }, { }] }
            ]
        };

        var table = new google.visualization.DataTable(data);

        var options = {
            legend: 'none',
            pointSize: 5
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(table, options);
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width:400; height:300"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Other than inserting fake/dummy values (which I don't want to do - this misrepresents the actual data), is there a way of doing this?

I've already tried setting the empty value to null, or empty - with no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

You automatically calculate the interval values on the fly, the only downside is that these values will show as points on the graph. You need to run the following after you've defined `data`:

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
    if(data.rows[i].c[1].v == undefined) {
        data.rows[i].c[1].v = (data.rows[i - 1].c[1].v + data.rows[i + 1].c[1].v) / 2;
    }
}
```

This loops through each row, checks if the value has been defined or not. If it hasn't, it will find the middle point between the next and previous point and make that the value. Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cchana/77Mwj/) of it working.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't insert fake or dummy values (which is what these would be).

Comment: Is it because they show a point? They are not really dummy data, just the midway point that gives you a way to connect the points. Will look for an alternative...

Comment: I want to show the points where they're in the source data - as it gives a user the ability to examine the data more closely, and see any applicable other info in the tool-tips. Inserting dummy data isn't suitable because they're not actually in the source data, and can lead to a user making incorrect assumptions about the data.

Comment: That makes sense, but looking around I can't see a way to do this on the x-axis. It seems you can specify two separate y-axis as this answer shows: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11358696/750593 but I tried doing it for the x-axis but it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue and got it fixed like this:

Use the `interpolateNulls` option as documented in the LineChart page: http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart.html#Configuration_Options

> Whether to guess the value of missing points. If true, it will guess the value of any missing data based on neighboring points. If false, it will leave a break in the line at the unknown point.

The option defaults to False, set it to true using `var options = {'interpolateNulls':true};`